# What factors other than Gibbs free energy determine formation of a compound?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetics

The $\Delta G_{f}^{\circ}$ value for $\ce{Fe2O3}$ is less negative than that of $\ce{Fe3O4}$ in JANAF table at room temperature but still, $\ce{Fe2O3}$ is what's formed. How does one explain this given that it's not the thermodynamically favored one?

Answer (score 2):

Thermodynamics only dictates whether or not the process is favorable. It gives no indication as to whether the process will actually take place or how quickly if it does.

You're asking about chemical kinetics which measures how quickly reactions proceed. In this case, the formation of the more stable product under ambient conditions is slow because the barrier to reaction is high.

Comment: I understood what you said and thanks for sharing this information but the thing is I am analysing a GdFe2 sample and XRD shows formation of Fe2O3 on it's surface rather than Fe3O4 (which has more negative"delta G") when the sample is left at room temperature for a long time (a few days). My question is why is Fe3O4 not forming instead based on Gibbs energy value and if I have to explain the formation of Fe2O3 what other factors or energies should I be looking at. As of now I read surface energy, interface energy and orientation of planes can be considered but what else should I consider?